# WSO2 OAuth2 global scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In IS I retrieve token by call `https://wso2is.local:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token%20token&client_id=NgTICXFPYnt7ETUm6Fc8NMU8K38a&redirect_uri=http://wso2is.local:8080/playground2/oauth2client&nonce=abc&scope=openid+scope_1+scope_2+scope_3`[1].

But when I try get token for all scopes my url becomes very long.

Can I make request e.g `scope=openid+global` ?

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Implicit+Client+Profile+with+Playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported due to security reasons. Only requested scopes are considered when issuing a token.

Comment: Is it possible share one scope on multiple apis on AM? If so, then I could request token by this scope.

Comment: No, because API developers are allowed to create their own scopes, therefore scope x can mean different meanings in different APIs. But from the application point of view, one should be able to say the meaning of each scope. Therefore, scopes with the same key are not allowed across APIs.

Comment: In APIM 3.0 (which is under development yet), there will be shared scopes. That solves your problem.